# When does the romance occur?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Mass Effect 2 had a very definite trigger point when the romance would culminate with your chosen paramour. If I remember correctly, Mass Effect 1 did as well.

Is there a certain mission or event that triggers it in this game, or does it happen some other way?

Comment: Wild Guess: When you launch the final assault, same as in the past 2 games.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I figure that's true, but I'll feel pretty dumb if I miss it because I made that assumption and didn't partake in some convoluted courting ritual

Comment: (Hopefully) after a few drinks and a night out on the ship; go see a movie, or take her to the fair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happens when you're ready to put all of your cards on the table, right before you

> attack the Cerberus base head-on in search of the Prothean V.I.

You'll have the typical "Are you sure?" dialogue (with Admiral Hackett) once you go to begin this mission.

As [CaulynDarr notes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/54544/4076), the actual Paramour achievement itself is awarded earlier in the game following the

> Cerberus attack on the Citadel

While I'm unsure of the specifics for all available romance options, a "successful" relationship with Liara in my playthrough revolved around three key conversation events:

- Liara asks about your other romance option in Mass Effect 2, if you had one
- Liara asks you to come to the Presidium Commons on the Citadel (Paramour achievement is awarded at this point)
- Liara visits you in your cabin prior to the final mission

Answer (score 2):

You get the Paramour achievement much earlier

> When you choose your romance partner after Cerberus attacks the Citadel.

When this happens some of the romance options include um..er..consummation.